# Floating point value equality with integral

Tags: c++, if-statement, floating-point, equality

This issue fundementally comes down to 2 lines, the 1st line will output 1.

```
std::cout << sqrt(pow(b->x - a->x, 2) + pow(b->y - a->y, 2) + pow(b->z - a->z, 2)) << std::endl;
```

Yet the 2nd line will output 0, how is this possible?

```
std::cout << (sqrt(pow(b->x - a->x, 2) + pow(b->y - a->y, 2) + pow(b->z - a->z, 2)) == 1) << std::endl;
```

Minimal complete verifiable example:

```
struct vertice {
    double x, y, z;
    vertice(double x, double y, double z) {
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y;
        this->z = z;
    }
};

void cartDistance(const vertice * a, const vertice * b);

int main() {
    cartDistance(new vertice(0, 0, 0), new vertice(0, 0, 1));
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void cartDistance(const vertice * a, const vertice * b) {
    std::cout << "dist: " << sqrt(pow(b->x - a->x, 2) + pow(b->y - a->y, 2) + pow(b->z - a->z, 2)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "dist check: " << (sqrt(pow(b->x - a->x, 2) + pow(b->y - a->y, 2) + pow(b->z - a->z, 2)) == 1) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: sorry, no these two lines are not enough. what is `b` what is `a` ? Please create a [mcve]

Comment: They are different. So what's the question?

Comment: do you expect `double x = 1; std::cout << (x == 1);` to print `1` ?

Comment: ...erm sorry misleading example, but still I guess the dupe has the answer for you

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I just realized 1 sec after hitting return. Nevertheless, in prinicple thats the misunderstanding (i guess...)

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://repl.it/repls/OrnateFancyRacerunner), assuming the first expression produces a value of 1, and the second uses the same unchanged values.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah [reproduced](https://repl.it/repls/BleakSpicyNutcracker)

Comment: @harold, Ah, well there wasn't any of the current information available before, so my comment really has no value. There was no indication whether the values were doubles, or ints.

Comment: @tobi303 I expect it to print 1 when the first statement prints 1.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah actually it doesn really matter, because `sqrt` returns a floating point in any case and just because in your case it printed `1` you cannot conclude that it is fine in general. Floating points should (almost) never be compared with `==`, even if sometimes it seems to work as expected

Comment: If integers are used, then don't use `pow` using integers, as even that is not guaranteed to be exact.

Comment: A tip: `std::hypot()` has much less error than `std::sqrt(std::pow()+std::pow()`.

Answer (score 2):

The stream output operator is rounding because you don't really want to see 0.999999999999999999997. The math is inexact, and that is being hidden from you. The comparison operator does care about this, though.

Floating point operations require care.

Using `std::setprecision ()` will allow you to see more digits after the decimal, at which point your problem will be more obvious.

Comment: I already suspected this, my question is effectively why is this happening it seems absurd to store data as such, and how does one deal with this problem.

Comment: @JonathanWoollett-light  For example, if you require exact maths for something like currency then you hold cents rather then dollars in an integer variable of the appropriate size.  Otherwise you need to deal with the fact that there are not enough bits in the universe to exactly represent number like 0.1 (base10) in base2 floating point.

Comment: Do you know any resources explaining why this occurs? From my knowledge of floating point values using mantissa and exponent it just doesn't seem reasonable that it cannot simply store 1 as 1 rather than some approximation.

Comment: The value `0.1` is irrational in binary. Multiplying it by 10 does not give you one because of this. How would you design a storage system to hold an infinite number of numbers in a finite space? The absurdity you see is a well-considered and intentional engineering decision upon which we have, literally, built the world you live in.

Comment: floats use binary fractions 1/2; 1/4; 1/8; 1/16 etc so in decimal they are 0.5, 0.25, 0.125; 0.0625 etc have a play trying to make 0.1 out of the above fractions.  Link to info: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/   In summary `0.1f * 10.0f != 1` it will be very close though.

Comment: @Jonathan: It can store 1. The problem is that if you ever do math on the 1, which you do here, it is very probably no longer exactly 1. Just very close. One typically does math to get a variable `a` and then asks if `std::abs (a-1)<1e-6` or some such. That is, you see if something is close enough.

Comment: @Richard: .1 is not irrational. Irrationality is a property of numbers; it is independent of any base used to represent them. You mean .1 is not exactly representable in a finite binary format.

Comment: @RichardCritten Well, [it *can* be](https://ideone.com/Crih7r) `0.1f * 10.0f == 1`. Implementations are allowed to use a greater precision for intermediate values. Still, for floating point values, it is always better to check if two  values are *almost* equal.

Comment: Thanks, @EricPostpischil. This was what I meant.